# Django model field max_length 3x varchar size?

Tags: django, django-models

I just realized that with a legacy table I'm using in a django app that a varchar(5) field (for example) is rendered in python as a models.CharField(max_length=15) field. This 3x size for the max length is very consistent across many other fields.

Why? or more importantly if I changed the django definition to be models.CharField(max_length=5) would I break anything?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a manual error by someone who tried to write models.

No. It doesn't break anything if you change it to 5. Not only that, you should change it to 5, so your form validation itself will take care of that length where you have that field.

Comment: sorry... I should have been more precise. When I said "rendered" above I meant that the Django code was created by the "python manage.py inspectdb" command So this was not the result of a manual error, unless you're including the author of the inspectdb command.